# Find number of Bytes read from Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I use `Selenium WebDriver` technology with `Java` and I have a question about these libraries:

Can I have the **number of bytes read** from my Chromedriver? Or the only thing that I can do is to get everytime the page source and analize it?

With a normal Java HTTP request I can do:

```
InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
bytedownloaded += is.available();
```

And so I can have the **weight of the downloaded data**.

There is something similar for Selenium? I need to improve my code watching what are the heavier requests.

If you know some alternative paths, I'd like to talk about them.

Thanks a lot for the help .

Comment: One way of doing it, request this information from the browser by javascript.

Comment: You mean something like :  
     `var pagebytes = $('html').html().length`
?

Comment: Yes, I hope this helps

Comment: This does not take xhr requests into account.